# Why were DS9's uniforms different?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-ds9, star-trek-uniforms

For DS9, they switched to the much less pajamic uniform style.

> [image]
>
> TNG style:  colorful body, collar, black shoulders, no undershirt.

whereas

> [image]
>
> DS9 style:  black body, colored shoulders, grayish undershirt.

Those uniforms were used in Voyager.

Eventually, everyone converts to this:

> [image]
>
> black body, gray shoulders, colored undershirt

Now, in the first DS9 episode, Sisko, O'Brien, Dax and Bashir are **all** shown in the TNG style uniform before they settle on DS9 and have chance to change uniforms.

So was the intent that they wear the less formal uniforms on DS9 because -- why -- because it's not a ship?   because it's the frontier?   because it's not Federation space?

This is confounded since they then go with the new uniforms for Voyager as well as the Enterprise-D in *Star Trek: Generations*, which seems to be as odds with the DS9/TNG schism.

So what exactly was supposed to be going on in-universe at the time with the uniforms?

Comment: Out of universe is easy. After the First Contact film, they had lots of extra uniforms and Borg props. They gave the new uniforms to the DS9 production crew and transferred the borg props and DS9 uniforms to the Voyager production team.

Comment: *"So was the intent that they wear the less formal uniforms on DS9 because -- why -- because it's not a ship?"* This wouldn't be the answer, because in *Star Trek: Generations* the crew of the Enterprise-D wear the *DS9*-style jumpsuits, even prior to *Voyager*.

Comment: @Praxis:   That's basically the same as Voyager taking on the new uniforms.   Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

## Allowance for informal, comfortable clothing while on duty.

I believe answer has to do with formality versus informality and comfort.

As far as four seasons into *DS9*, we see the *TNG*-style duty uniforms still being used.  They appear in the episode ["Homefront"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Homefront_(episode)).  When Sisko returns to Earth to meet Admiral Leyton, Admiral Leyton wears the *TNG*-style admiral's uniform and his aide wears the *TNG*-style duty uniform:

[image]

In the background we can see other officers in the *TNG*-style uniform.  **In particular, Sisko changes back into a *TNG*-style uniform for his meeting with Leyton.**

We have already ruled out that the *DS9*-style jumpsuits were intended for use exclusively on space stations, given that they are used on the Enterprise-D in *Generations* and on Voyager.  Since officers based at Starfleet Command are still wearing the older uniforms in the fourth season of *DS9*, and since Sisko made the point of changing into them for his visit to Starfleet Command, the suggestion is that the *TNG*-era uniforms are *more formal*.

In turn, this suggests that officers on starships and Starfleet installations were offered the jumpsuit as an alternative to the *TNG*-era uniforms, perhaps for comfort while working.  Consistent with this, the "Homefront" example shows that the jumpsuits might not be deemed as suitable for official business as the *TNG*-era uniforms.

So in the years leading up to the fleet-wide shift to the grey-topped *First Contact*-period uniforms, the *TNG* and the *DS9*-style uniforms were in use concurrently, with context dictating which was more appropriate.

This screenshot from the Enterprise bridge in *Generations* shows both in use at the same time:

[image]

Most telling is that Riker begins the film in a *TNG*-style uniform, but when things begin to heat up, he changes into a *DS9* jumpsuit.  Comfort is important when you're about the crash the saucer section into a planet!

Comment: excellent find on "Homefront".   Then the corollary is, Why did the Enterpise-D switch?   Picard seems the kind of guy that prefers the formality.   Okay, may be except for Troi.  And himself with that jacket thing.  Okay, I take it back.

Comment: @ThePopMachine : I was just adding a little more info about the Enterprise, actually.  :-)

Comment: Now that screencap is just weird.  Four new, four old.   Were they trying to make a smooth transition for the audience or something?

Comment: I wonder whether some reference to real-world uniform usage precedent would be a good addition?

Comment: @ThePopMachine : It might be -- I'll have a think and possibly work on it this evening.

Comment: @ThePopMachine There is somewhere on another question/answer, someone said it may have been an attempt to mimic real-life uniform changes, where they're only replaced slowly over years instead of all at once.  But also that it doesn't exactly make sense thanks to the replicator

Comment: I'm surprised no one has mentioned this, but in-universe the "jumpsuit" style is called a "Utility Uniform" vs. a "Duty Uniform". It's basically the same thing the Academy cadets wear but without the pockets on the legs. Note that after the utility style became common, cadet uniforms were changed to a light grey with red shoulders. The heavier-fabric uniforms with the grey shoulders and less color were a by-product of The Dominion War.

Comment: @ThePopMachine - I just noticed, that screenshot actually has all three uniform styles used up to Generations. Four in the new utility uniform (3 command, 1 operations), Picard & Worf in the jacket-style duty uniform (command & operations), and the other two crewmen in the original jumpsuit-style duty uniform (operations).

Comment: @Omegacron: What do you mean by jacket style vs. original jumpsuit? I don't see any difference.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper - in the early seasons of TNG, everyone wore a single-piece jumpsuit. In season 3, they changed the main cast to a 2-piece uniform consisting of pants and jacket. You can tell by how it fits across the chest and the neck.

Comment: @Omegacron: I know, but that jumpsuit (at least in its unmodified form) is not visible in that photo from Generations. The uniforms introduced in season 3 came with a collar (which is featured on both crewmen's uniforms here), whereas the season 1 + 2 jumpsuits had no collar and a coloured piping in the black area, which is not present on the crewmen's uniforms here.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper - ah ok, I see what you mean now. Other than the collar, the two in gold (guy at Ops, girl next to Worf) seem to be in S1 uniforms... but you're right, no collar on those. I guess maybe those are just thinner since they're background characters.

Comment: @Omegacron:  We can also see by the zipper down the front of the guy at ops.  At least, I think it is visible.

Answer (score 7):

To put into modern context, even the Navies around the world have multiple "duty" uniforms and some are more formal than other or flat out dress uniforms.

For instance, when on duty at headquarters battalion administration and security will be in dress uniforms while general troops are wearing camoflauge utilities or blouse & slacks. This extends even to on ship where Utilities generally become the "formal" and coveralls become the "utilities".

Then there is such a thing as "Uniform of the Day" where the CO has near-absolute jurisdiction over what his command wears at any given time so long as it is not in violation of the established clothing code.

I doubt there was that much though put into it in Star Trek, but it doesn't seem too odd in context with modern times. As far as the grey shoulder uniform goes, it was likely a more subtle way of making every one similar in war time (Dominion) while still keeping the occupational specialty segregation.

Answer (score 2):

Non-Canon answer (its based on evidence from Star Trek Online)

In the 2410s, Starfleet had a policy where captains and other commanding officers had discretion over their personal and crew uniforms, departing from a standard. The new "Oddysey" style uniform was adopted for all general staff and those crews who had not opted for a custom uniform

> STARFLEET MEMORANDUM
>
> Stardate 87003.8
>
> FROM: Fleet Admiral Jorel Quinn
>
> Starfleet Command
>
> TO: All Starship and Station Commanders
>
> REGARDING STARFLEET UNIFORM CODE
>
> This memorandum is to inform you of updates to the Starfleet Uniform Code Subsection 1 effective Stardate 87003.
>
> As the political realities throughout Federation space continue to shift,
>   Starfleet must remain a force for consistency and stability. To that end, the
>   admiralty is enacting a fleet-wide update and standardization of the Starfleet
>   duty uniform. Starfleet has officially and totally adopted the uniform designated
>   “Odyssey”, which has already seen initial deployment by personnel on Earth
>   Spacedock in Sector 001 and in several fleet command starbases across the
>   quadrant.
>
> The Odyssey uniform design provides a solid link to Starfleet’s heritage while
>   establishing a bold direction for its future.
>   Attached to this message are replicator patterns for the Odyssey uniform. We
>   have authorized all starship and station commanders to begin replication and
>   distribution of this uniform among their crews effective immediately. Please
>   also see the attached uniform specifications on appropriate accessories,
>   coloration and wear.
>
> NOTE: Subsection 2, Paragraph 1 of the Starfleet Uniform Code remains in
>   effect; Starship captains continue to have discretion as to their personal
>   uniform and the uniforms of their bridge crew.
>
> In service,
>
> Fleet Admiral Jorel Quinn
>
> Starfleet Command, Earth Spacedock

[Source](http://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/startrek/images/0/0f/Starfleet_Uniform_Code_2410_web.pdf/revision/latest?cb=20140719235840)

It is possible that this policy existed in a similar fashion back in the DS9 Era, and Sisko was given leeway to select station uniforms to his liking and to fit the needs of the base. In this case, Terok Nor was an inustrial mining platform that had been stripped and sabotaged by the Cardassians. There was a LOT of dirty grubby work to do. To this end he may have selected the workman's jumpsuit style uniform out of prudence to the work needing doing.

When Starfleet released the grey First Contact style uniform later on, Sisko likely decided that the need for the rugged jumpsuit variation had passed, and opted for the more militarized look to meet the needs of the growing conflict with the Dominion.

Other evidence to show this trend was the moderate continued use of the skintight uniform on TNG well into the general use of the Starfleet Duty Uniform used in the latter half of TNG, along with various scientific outposts using slightly modified uniforms through all series. Seen [here](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Starfleet_uniform_(late_2360s-early_2370s)) for training, excursion, flight suit, B'elanna Torres's work jacket, as well as personal modifications such as Worf's Sash, Bajoran Earrings, Maternity alterations, Combat uniforms, MACO gear, etc.

Comment: I find it hard to see how a non-canon memorandum from something like 40 (!) years in the future informs us much about DS9.

Comment: shows a continued pattern, but I informed at the beginning its not a show/movie canon answer.

Comment: Fanfic is fun, but it's not really that useful when the OP is asking for an in-universe answer.

Answer (score 2):

Out of universe answer DS9 was set in a grittier shades of gray setting, so the black uniform symbolized the darker theme of the show.

My experience is there is a duty uniform i.e. BDU's, which is normally worn. Depending on your specific job you could wear blues; blue pants, with a light blue shirt, a tie is optional. I the medical field the wear of scrubs was allowed. The unit commander could designate which uniform was to be worn normally, and could specify that a certain uniform to be worn on a specific day. Blues day, or BDU day.

Answer (score 1):

The DS9 uniforms seen in the first five seasons were originally conceived to be exclusive for space station crew members. You can see that reflected on the show itself when Starfleet guest stars from either ships or HQ only wore TNG style uniforms, and when Sisko visited HQ he would wear TNG uniform.

For various production reasons, it was decided that GENERATIONS and VOYAGER would feature DS9 uniforms, despite conflicting with the original premise of those uniforms. Apparently that decision was made because the DS9 costumes were much more comfortable for actors to wear than the more cumbersome TNG costumes. If production wanted to more consistent about the depiction of TNG/DS9 uniforms, they would have had GENERATIONS and VOYAGER strictly wear the TNG uniforms while DS9 would keep theirs.

Comment: Do you have a source for this?